# How to trim a string based on the co-occurrence of two patterns out of a group of several pairs of patterns?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of input strings and a list of tuples with each tuple containing a pair of string patterns:

```
list_strings=["ABC","ABCDEF","CDEFGH","AB","CDEFGHIJK","DEFGHIJKLMNO"]
list_patterns=[("A","C"),("CDE","JK"),("EF","MNO")
```

What I'm trying to do is basically cut the strings from `list_strings` in the position where they find any of the patterns in `list_patterns`. So for each string, I want to retrieve the characters in between the first and second member of any of the tuples in the `list_patterns` list.

It does not matter which tuples of patterns I use to cut the strings, I just want to keep what's in between the first and second member of each tuple (trimmed string).

The output string will contain the trimmed string obtained with first matching pattern; if there are no matching patterns the original string will be preserved. Furthermore, I want to create also a list containing the strings which were successfully trimmed.

My output would be something like this:

```
list_containing_all_strings=["B","B","CDEFGH","AB","FGHI","GHIJKL"]
list_containing_successful_trims=["B","B","FGHI","GHIJKL"]
```

Comment: First of all: what would be the output in case an input string can be trimmed by more than a pattern?How would you choose the one to be placed in the output string (as far as I understand `list_containing_all_strings` will have the same number of members of `list_strings`

Comment: Basically it's irrelevant what tuple of patterns I use to cut the strings, so if a string can be trimmed by more than one, I would like it to simply be trimmed by the first it encounters (that's why I considered putting the tuples inside a set and not a list). 
Yes, those will have the same number of members.

Comment: Then: I would come up with an idea without regex. Are you bound to use it? If yes, as it could be not immediate for all readers, could you include your attempt so that is clear how you are going to use it?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I probably misused the regex tag, I doesn't need to be used at all. I'll correct that and remove the tag thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just iterate over the list elements. For each of them I would try searching the trimming patterns until one of them is found:

```py
input_list=["ABC","ABCDEF","CDEFGH","AB","CDEFGHIJK","DEFGHIJKLMNO"]
list_patterns=[("A","C"),("CDE","JK"),("EF","MNO")]

output_list = []
trimmed_list = []

for el in input_list:
    for pat in list_patterns:
        beg = el.find(pat[0])
        end = el.rfind(pat[1])
        if(beg != -1 and end != -1):
            trimmed_list.append(el[beg+len(pat[0]):end])
            output_list.append(el[beg+len(pat[0]):end])
            break
    else:
        output_list.append(el)
        
print(output_list)
print(trimmed_list)
```

- Both `output_list` and `trimmed_list` are empty, at first.
- For each couple element-pattern, perform a straight search of the starting pattern (`find()` on `pat[0]`) and a reverse search of the closing pattern (`rfind()` on `pat[1]`)
- Only if both of them have been found (check against -1) append the correct string *slice* of the original string to both `output_list` and `trimmed_list` and `break`
- For each element, whenever the pattern were not found (`else`), append the original string to `output_list`

**The output:**

```
['B', 'B', 'CDEFGH', 'AB', 'FGHI', 'GHIJKL']
['B', 'B', 'FGHI', 'GHIJKL']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Regex-Patterns**.

It might seem pretty complicated to begin with, but once you get the hang of it, it works like a charm.

The way you can use regex is that you specify a pattern which a string is supposed to match and then retrieve a group that you specified in your pattern.

A quick regex pattern for your example would be:

```
^(A)?(CDE)?(EF)?(\w+)(C)?(JK)?(MNO)?$
```

where you can backreference group 4 (\w+) in order to get your wanted substring.

The given example only works when you know that the strings will only be in alphabetical order, but I am certain that you can find a pattern that exactly suits your needs.

Here are [some references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for information and I always use [this site](https://regexr.com/) to test various patterns I write.

*Note: Watch out how you format the pattern, as storing it in a string can require some additional commenting.*